# Polymer google-chart table css

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to insert css in my google-chart table.

My code

```
var cssClassNames = {'headerRow': 'cssHeaderRow',
                  'tableRow': 'cssTableRow',
                  'oddTableRow': 'cssOddTableRow',
                  'selectedTableRow': 'cssSelectedTableRow',
                  'hoverTableRow': 'cssHoverTableRow',
                  'headerCell': 'cssHeaderCell',
                  'tableCell': 'cssTableCell',
                  'rowNumberCell': 'cssRowNumberCell'
              };
var options = {page: 'enable', pageSize:20, height:'100%',
              sort:'enable', showRowNumber: true, width: '100%',
              showRowNumber: true,
              alternatingRowStyle:true, allowHtml: true, 
              cssClassNames: cssClassNames}
this.$.chart_class.options = options;
```

But it's not working.
I have added

`this.$.chart_class.set('options', options);`

and

`this.$.chart_class.redraw();`

I need to style the pagination too.

Comment: In my understanding I need to add css to google-chart-styles. I doing it by modifying the google-chart-styles html, but can I do it by my app html?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide full code and what exactly you need but if you have already chart exist and you need styling of chart then you may use element's styling :

```
<template>
<style>
google-chart {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50em;
  ......
}
..... 
</style> 

 <google-chart
  type="{{type}}"
  options="{{options}}"
  cols="{{cols}}"
  rows="{{rows}}">
</google-chart>
```

In case if you need to specify google-chart property dynamically than specify cols and rows, besides your options are not formatted as into element [description](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/elements/google-chart). But simply you may use and define properties dynamically:

At the property declaration, you may define this properties and options. Or in a function with the button or somehow with calling this function:

```
defininingChartVariables(){
    var type = "pie"  // See the possible types below link.
    var cols = [<specify an array for cols>];
    var rows = [<specify an array for rows>];
    var options = {title: "Chart title goes here",
                   hAxis: {title: "Categories"},
                   vAxis: {title: "Values", minValue: 0, maxValue: 2},
                   legend: "none" };
    this.set('type',type);
    this.set('cols',cols);
    this.set('rows',rows);
    this.set('optiosn',options);
}
```

- see the possible [types](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/elements/google-chart#property-type)